# reading variables from properties file in bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell, variables, scripting

How to escape the special characters in variables when reading from properties file using shell scripting. The properties file has key and value and the key has period(.) symbol in it. This period symbol in the key is treated as executable and bash is executing it. I put the double quotes in the variable expansion but still throwing the error. What am i doing wrong here.

```
#!/bin/bash

source my-sonar.properties

for servicename in `cat  my-services.input`
do
 # Both variable expansions are not working.
 echo $servicename ${sonar.host.url} ${sonar.login}
 echo $servicename "$sonar.host.url" "$sonar.login"
done
```

root# cat my-sonar.properties

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/sonar/
sonar.login=sonar-token-string
```

root# cat my-services.input

```
javaservice-one
javaservice-two
```

Below is the error i am seeing.

```
my-sonar.properties: line 1: sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000/sonar/: No such file or directory
my-sonar.properties: line 2: sonar.login=sonar-token-string: command not found
./sonar-execute.sh: line 7: ${sonar.host.url}: bad substitution
```

Comment: `sonar.host.url` is not a valid variable name. If you want to set a bash variable, choose a valid variable name.

Comment: That means without dots.

Comment: If you have bash version 4 or 5, you could use an associative array instead: `declare -A properties; properties["sonar.host.url"]=http://localhost:9000/sonar/` etc. BTW, you [shouldn't read lines with a `for` loop](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: Also, see [BashFAQ/001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: I came too came across associative arrays and it a nice option for declaring variables. I was setting the key/value in properties in java format and tried to use the same variable which is issue. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer the dots during the sourcing (and change the code where you use it):

```
source <(tr "." "_" < my-sonar.properties)
echo "${sonar_login}"
```

EDIT:
This solution neglects any dots right of the '=' sign. This can be improved by
source <(sed ':a;s/[.]([^=]*=)/_\1/g;ta' my-sonar.properties)

Be aware that someone who can edit the properties file, can also insert unix commands that will be executed under your account.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will change dots to underscores in the value as well as the property name. For example, "sonar.host.url=http://www.example.com/sonar/" -> "sonar_host_url=http://www_example_com/sonar/".

Comment: @GordonDavisson Tx, I also added a warning for people inserting `rm *` in the property file.

Comment: @Gordon/Walter good to know to replace the variable and source. defined the java format variables in shell script directly is the issue. Replacing the dot with underscore will change the variable but can not invoke the maven command with variable.properties in the shell script. so I have to use single quote like below. SONAR_OPTS='-Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost.localdomain/sonar/ -Dsonar.login=<...> -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0' and invoke ($MAVEN_GOAL $SONAR_OPTS "$SONAR_PROJECT""$servicename" "$SONAR_KEY" servicename ) But I am not sure which is right or wrong to use in shell script.